# ClassNotFoundException despite class seemingly still there

Tags: android

I have an app in which I have

```
public class mainactivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
...
```

and I declare it in that manifest. Everything compiles and runs perfectly. Then I change the class as follows:

```
public class mainactivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener , MoPubInterstitialListener
{
...
+ extra code to do with "mopub"
```

this new code compiles, but now, as soon as my splash screen activity shuts down and hands over to mainactivity, I see

```
03-08 10:47:40.380: I/dalvikvm(9013): Failed resolving Lcom/mycompany/myapp/mainactivity; interface 1127 'Lcom/mopub/mobileads/MoPubInterstitial$MoPubInterstitialListener;'
03-08 10:47:40.380: W/dalvikvm(9013): Link of class 'Lcom/mycompany/myapp/mainactivity;' failed
03-08 10:47:40.380: D/AndroidRuntime(9013): Shutting down VM
03-08 10:47:40.380: W/dalvikvm(9013): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c7e1f8)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.mainactivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.myapp.mainactivity
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1891)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1992)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1158)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4511)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:980)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:747)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.myapp.mainactivity
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1026)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1882)
03-08 10:47:40.385: E/AndroidRuntime(9013):     ... 11 more
```

I'm at a loss as to how to proceed. If I try the debugger it appears that not even the first line of mainactivity.OnCreate() is executed.

EDIT: I have the following included in my manifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity"
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

Comment: can you put your manifest file

Comment: Is your namespace correct? `com.mycompany.myapp`

Comment: Your entire manifest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Classpath

If this ring a bell, then read on.

***Diagnosis:***
It means the compiler find these classes during `compile-time` but this class is not found in your classpath during `runtime`

***Medicine:***
I've had this before and am not perfectly sure of the steps but ***let me put you in the right direcction.***

- If you're using ADT and eclipse, check your `.classpath` in your project.
- check the **build order** in **project->build properties**
- check if your jar is included in the **build path**

### isLibraryProject

If the `ComponentInfo` is part of a library project, then it's a `CardinalSin` (seriously!) to include it in your build path manually. You are ***supposed to*** just add is a  library project in `project properties->android` tab.

Answer (score 0):

Did you define the MoPub activity in your Manifest?

```
<activity android:name="com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubActivity"
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"/>
```

Go have a look at [this](http://help.mopub.com/customer/portal/articles/285194-android-integration-part-ii-interstitials) link. It should solve your problem.

Comment: There's something else going on, though. Just adding another interface declaration to a class shouldn't cause a problem. The OP didn't post the extra code for mopub, and as a result, it might seem to readers that just adding the new interface caused the problem.

Comment: I'm guessing the MoPubActivity is then defined in your manifest? If you do the MoPub implementation without implementing another interface  like in the link, does it still get the same issue?

Comment: Where are you seeing this MoPubActivity? He makes 0 mention of it. Do you mean mainactivity ?

Comment: In your manifest file below your main activity, add the code I showed above for the MoPubActivity and try it again. You have to define the library activity for it to work.

Comment: @Neil: Sorry for slow reply, but  I did already have this in my manifest.

Comment: Please post the whole Error stack that you get in logcat

Comment: I think you should try the method in the link I suggested. That should work

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I checked on the android-support-v4.jar checkbox under Java Build Path - Order and Export.